# Using Riemann criterion for integrability to prove integrability of the function $F$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

$F(1/n) = 1$ for $n=1,2,3..$

Else $F(x) = 0$

I considered the uniform partition $[0,1/N,...1/2, 1]$

But then the upper Riemann sum is always equal to one and the lower one always equal to 0.. what partition should I consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $\epsilon < 1$ take partition points $0$, $1/k - \epsilon/2^{k+3}, 1/k + \epsilon/2^{k+3}$ for $k = 2, \ldots, N$,  $1 - \epsilon/8$, and $1$.

Then $L(P,f) = 0$ and $U(P,f) =  \frac{1}{N} - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{N+3}} + \epsilon\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{2^{k+2}} < \epsilon$ for sufficiently large $N$.

When $\epsilon \geqslant 1$ take $P= (0,1)$.

Comment: What do you mean that they do not overlap? Also, would it suffice to take intervals like 1/N +-epsilon, and then take N as large as we need for things to work out in the end?

Comment: Intervals with points $1/k \pm \epsilon$ won't work since $U(P,f) = O(N\epsilon)$

Comment: The points must be ordered $1 > x_1 > x_2 >  \ldots > 0$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with big O notation.. Also, how do we know that they do not overlap in this partition?

Comment: Forget big O.  You can see with your partition  there are at least $N$ subintervals of width $2\epsilon$ where the supremum of $f$ is $1$ so $U(P,f) \geqslant 2N \epsilon$.  Plus you have the contribution from the last interval which is $1 \cdot (1 - 1/2 + \epsilon) = 1/2 + \epsilon$.

Comment: My points are $1, 1 - \epsilon/8, 1/2 + \epsilon/ 32, 1/2 - \epsilon/32, \dots$ when $\epsilon < 1$.  Notice that $1 > 1 - 1/8 = 7/8 = 28/32 > 1/2 + 1/32 = 17/32> \ldots$.

Comment: It still isn't clear how you came up with that particular partition.. the $k+3$ in particular seems arbitrary

Comment: It is not entirely arbitrary. There are other choices, but this one happens to work. To form a partition you need an ordered set of points $0 < x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_m < 1$. In this way the subintervals $I_j = [x_{j-1},x_j]$ are not overlapping. Since $f(x) = 1$ only at $x = 1/n$ we also need $\sum_{ 1/n \in I_j, n \in \mathbb{N}} l(I_j) < \epsilon$ where $l(I_j)$ is the interval length.  This can be achieved if we make the interval $I_{n_j}$ containing the point $1/n$ of length $\delta_n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \delta_n \leqslant \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you. Would a partition of the form [0, 1\N, 1\(N-1) - delta, 1\N-1 + delta, ... 1/2 + delta, 1] work? We make N large so that the contribution of the interval [0,1/N] is small, and we make delta small enough that the intervals do not overlap, and the contribution from each interval of the form [1/k - delta, 1/k + delta] is small, and the function is zero on every other interval.

Comment: The deltas have to diminish at a rate such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \delta_n$ converges.

Comment: So.. delta = 1/N^2 would work provided we can make the intervals disjoint? So delta = min ( 1/N^2, z) where z is the smallest of the differences 1/K-1 - 1/K?

Comment: Yes - that should work.